# Layout is weird and there is multiple ones that is the same/wrong spot

Tags: system

[image]

What did I do here...I accidentally added new things (IDK what it is called but the picture shows).
How do you get rid of this and bring it back to the default layout? With no extra stuff...I have no idea how...

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I would advice to get the basic stuff like using the UI on your own before continuing. It might not be practical to ask for every small detail like this. But, sure, the answer is not difficult at all.

Just grab a corner of some editor and drag it towards another to merge the UI areas:

[image]

Please note that it makes a difference what side you click on. If you drag towards another area from where you clicked it merges them, if you drag towards the area you clicked in it splits it into 2.

You can also right-click the line between them to get a menu with options:

[image]

And there are also layout presets on the top that you can chose:

[image]

And if you click the + button at the end you can create new layouts from default presets:

[image]

Don't worry, if yours are not identical to mine in the GIFs, they can be customized. There is nothing wrong with defaults, mine are just what I use most.

Comment: ah, thank you so much for the GIFs! It helped and mines is back to normal ^^